# cURL Upload file and send POST data

Tags: curl

I have a web server running some PHP that checks for an image (`curl -F 'imageName=@myimage'`) and it also checks the POST data for `username=&password=`.

When the PHP checks `_REQUEST` I cannot just do:

```
curl -F 'imageName=@myimage' \
'http://www.example.com/?upload=1&username=test&password=test'
```

I need to instead check `_POST` for username and password due to specs. How can I upload the image and have the `username=&password=` post data?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah found out one way to do this through the man pages.

Have to use -F 'username=test' -F 'password=test' I can't combine them with &. Weird

If anyone knows another way let me know =)

Comment: Why is that a problem, anyway? It's not like you have to pay extra for a second `-F`. (Sorry for that.) You cannot combine them with `&` because `-F` makes `curl` send a `multipart/form-data` request, which uses a completely different way of separating fields. You _could_ use `-d` instead, which sends the POST request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but it's _absolutely_ unsuitable for file uploads.